# Angular Material Reactive form radio button group not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to implement Angular Material radio group in my application, I get the following error:

```
  ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.
at getMatFormFieldMissingControlError
```

here is my code:

component:

```
    this.taskForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  Schedule: ['', Validators.required],
  StartDate: ['', Validators.required],
  EndDate: ['', Validators.required],

});
```

component.html:

```
   <div>
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <label id="example-radio-group-label">Schedule: </label>
                        <mat-radio-group aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label" *ngFor="let season of seasons" formControlName="Schedule" class="example-radio-group">
                            <label for="{{season}}" class="radio-inline"></label>
                            <mat-radio-button id="{{season}}"  class="example-radio-button"  [value]="season" [checked]="season==='Spring'" >
                                {{season}}
                            </mat-radio-button>
                        </mat-radio-group>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4 mat-radio-group with mat-form-field return Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188022/angular-4-mat-radio-group-with-mat-form-field-return-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix two things in your code:

1- Put your code outside of mat-form-field, read more (https://v5.material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview)

2- update your code and put ngFor inside mat-radio-button

```
       <div>
                        <label id="example-radio-group-label">Schedule: </label>
                        <mat-radio-group aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label" formControlName="Schedule" class="example-radio-group">
                            <label for="{{season}}" class="radio-inline"></label>
                            <mat-radio-button id="{{season}}"  *ngFor="let season of seasons" class="example-radio-button"  [value]="season" >
                                {{season}}
                            </mat-radio-button>
                        </mat-radio-group>
                </div>
```